# How Can I Restart The Redis Server If It Goes Down Automatically using a script?

Tags: bash, redis, node-redis

Redis has master slave configuration.If the master goes down,slave becomes the new master.How can i restart the previous redis master ( as a slave of new master or if it again become master that's fine ) using a script.I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Show us what you have done?

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala my master is running at port 6379 and my slave at 6380 and 6381.And using sentinel.conf  i am deciding the future master if the master goes down.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala using "redis-cli -p 6379 DEBUG sleep 30" i am killing my master and the slave becomes the master.But the earlier master is neither slave nor a master.So i want to restart it. Manually i did it but can i write any script for this

Answer (score 7):

This can be done using a small script. Make a watcher script that keeps pinging REDIS at port 6379 and if it fails. Just restart the server using redis-server command.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(redis-cli -p 6379 PING)
if [ "$a" = "PONG" ]
then
    echo 'Already running'
else
    b=$(/etc/init.d/redis_6379 start)   
    echo $b
fi
```

Now schedule this script in crontab for everyone minute.

Answer (score 5):

I had to teach myself after a catastrophic server failure caused by Redis dying and staying dead:

1. Edit `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/redis.service` and add this in the `[Service]` section, at the bottom:

   ```ini
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=10s
   ```
2. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Run `sudo systemctl restart redis`

It will now restart after 10 seconds every time it crashes.

This is usually "good enough" for Redis.

Answer (score 2):

Taking from the answers above, I have added a bit more descriptions to make it easier to understand.

Step One:  Create a script on the root folder, or on a folder of your choice
with the command:

```
vi redis-watch.sh
```

Step two: Paste the script below:

```
 #!/bin/bash
a=$(redis-cli -p 6379 PING)
if [ "$a" = "PONG" ]
then
    echo 'Already running'
else
    b=$(systemctl start redis)
    echo $b
fi
```

Save the changes.

Step three: Change the permissions of the file to prevent permission denied response on execution. Run:

```
sudo chmod 777 redis-watch.sh
```

Test if the script executes. Run:

```
./redis-watch.sh
```

The expected response should be  `Already running` if Redis is already running okay else the script will start redis.

Step four: To automate the check, create a cronjob to run the script with an interval of your choosing.  For our case we will have it running every second.

Run : `crontab -e` and paste the line:

```
* * * * * ./redis-watch.sh
```

That should be it.

Tested on `Cent OS 8`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(redis-cli -p 6379 PING)
if ["$a" != "PONG" ]
    b=$(systemctl start redis)
    echo $b
fi
```

Comment: Could you please add some explaini8ng text to your post

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24478714).

Answer (score 0):

Run

```bash
$ redis-cli

> config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
> exit
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32571691)