# Rescue from Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) for RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I know this error is due to Redis server being down that can start working by restarting the redis server. However, how do I rescue from this error to avoid crash on Production?

**Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)**

Answer (score 0):

There probably should not be a rescue from this issue, as this would mean anyehere in your code where you rescue, you would need to provide an alternative path for rescue to take.

Sometimes pain helps us to find and solve the source of a problem. Redis should not do down in production. If it does it should be restarted automatically.

For production loads, consider using infrastructure tools like Monit to monitor that Redis is up and running on the specified port and if it goes down automatically restarts redis. Or a script as per this answer below.

[How Can I Restart The Redis Server If It Goes Down Automatically using a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669437/how-can-i-restart-the-redis-server-if-it-goes-down-automatically-using-a-script)